How to apply a slope limiter (minmod) to the Discontinuous Galerkin (DG) method?
I've been trying to solve a PDE using the DG method for a while now. The DG method is implemented correctly but I still need to implement a slope limiter and would like to use the minmod limiter. The problem is that I used a nodal expansion and for the minmod limiter I need the modal coefficients. I'm now thinking of calculating the modal coefficients from the nodal points:
The representation of a nodal basis is given by:
$$u(t,x)= \sum _{j=1}^N u^j(t) \phi_j(x)$$
where $\phi_j$ are the Lagrange Polynomials and $u^j$ the nodal values at the points $x^j$.
The representation of the modal basis are given by:
$$u(t,x)= \sum _{k=0} ^{N-1} c^k(t) P_k(x) $$
where $P_k(x)$ are for example Legendre basis functions and satisfy the orthogonality property.
$$\int _{-1}^1 P_k P_k = \gamma _k \delta _{kl}$$
Now the nodal points $u^j$ can be transformed into the modal coefficients $c^k$ by
$$c_i^k=\sum_{j=1}^N u_i^j \int_{-1}^1 \phi_j(x) P_k(x) d x$$
This can be written in matrix form:
$$C=T U$$
with $$T_{k j}=\int_{-1}^1 \phi_j(x) P_k(x) d x$$.
With these I can apply the minmod limiter and use the inverse Transformation $T^{-1}$ to obtain the nodal values again.
This seem to be numerically pretty heavy and would need to be done after every time step. Is there another method and is what I wrote down even correct?

A basis transformation on the nodes of each cell (via a matrix-vector product with a matrix you have to compute only once) seems pretty cheap to me. You seem to be concerned about the computational cost -- have you actually times how much this costs?

No I didn't, but I will try now. I was concerned that this may not be the right approach so I was hesitant of investing the time. But I will apply it now. Thanks a lot :)!

It is widely observed in the software industry that even good programmers cannot predict where their codes are going to be slow. One really has to time and benchmark things to know. A corollary is that you generally can't know whether an approach is expensive unless you actually implement it.

You can also implement a limiter without converting to modal basis, see an implementation in deal.II here https://github.com/cpraveen/fem/tree/master/dg1d/scalar_lagrange

For people that may have the same question. It was not computationally expensive, since the matrix only had to be calculated once.
I also applied the minmod limiter to the solution sol(t) -> minmod(sol(t)) instead of doing it somehow in the time loop.
